# Ubuntu 14.04 - Command not found crashes because of locale

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, local

when I mistype a command, the command not found crashes:

```
root@stack1:~# fubar
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.4.3 final 0
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
Exception information:

'locale' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 12: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 24, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 72, in main
    enable_i18n()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 41, in enable_i18n
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/locale.py", line 592, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'locale' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 12: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a localization problem.

The appropriate course of action to address your problem is included in the error message. File a bug with the Ubuntu team at the URL provided.

Answer (score 0):

One of your .mo files seems to be damaged. Run `dpkg --list |grep language-pack-` and check what locale packages are instaled, then reinstall/update them all with `apt-get --reinstal install ...`. It may be helpful to run `apt-get update` first.

Also check your filesystem for possible other corruptions.